# changing text format to date format

Tags: database, string, date, mysql-workbench

There is a table named **job_data** in my database and it have one column named **ds** which contains date. But the ds column is in text format rather than date format. I have been trying to change it using cast and str_to_date functions, but both of them are giving output as null.

```sql
select str_to_date(ds, "%y/%m/%d") from job_data;

select ds, date_format(cast(ds as date), '%m%d%y') as ds from job_data;
```

These are the queries I used.

Please help me how to change the ds column from text to date format.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post sample values for column `ds` in `job_data` [database] table.